# Aggregating in arrays

Tags: arrays, r, aggregate

The netCDF4 file I want to work with in R is too large. I want to write a loop that will read in a chunk of the data and summarize it.

The variable I wish to read in has 4 dimensions; 'lat', 'lon', 'member' and 'time'. The time has a monthly resolution and the member contains 60 ensemble runs from a climate model.

Using the `ncvar_get` command I have extracted 12 time slices from the netCDF, leaving me with a 4 dimension array.

```
num[1:144,1:69:1:60,1:12]
```

How would I aggregate this so that I would have annual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your fourth dimension, which has a length of 12 is the number of months and you would like to aggregate over this dimension and return an array of dimension `c(144, 69, 60)`.

reproducible data (an array of the same dimensions, with all 1s)

```
myArray <- array(1, dim =c(144, 69, 60, 12))
```

Here is a method using `apply`:

```
mySumArray <- apply(myArray, c(1,2,3), sum)
```

This returns an array with the following dimensions:

```
dim(mySumArray)
[1] 144  69  60
```

and where the first three elements are:

```
mySumArray[1:3]
[1] 12 12 12
```

If you wanted the mean or some other function, just replace `sum` with you desired function.

An optimized version of summing and calculating the mean is `rowSums` and `rowMeans`.

```
mySumArray <- rowSums(myArray, dims=3)
```

returns the same result as above MUCH faster.